# cache config in API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, aws-api-gateway

I have below config in my code, but it's not enabling the cache in my API gateway.  Is there anything that's missing here?

```
custom:
  dev:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      RestApiId: 'REST_ID'
      CacheClusterEnabled: true
      CacheClusterSize: '0.5'
      MethodSettings:
         - ResourcePath: '/*'
          CacheTtlInSeconds: 300
```

Comment: You can try setting [CachingEnabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-stage-methodsetting.html#cfn-apigateway-stage-methodsetting-cachingenabled) for your `MethodSettings`.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks. I did, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```yaml
custom:
  dev:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      RestApiId: 'REST_ID'
      CacheClusterEnabled: true
      CacheClusterSize: '0.5'
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: '/*'
          HttpMethod: '*'
          CachingEnabled: true
          CacheTtlInSeconds: 300
```

If it doesn't work, try with a *resource path* and *method* explicit like:

```yaml
custom:
  dev:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      RestApiId: 'REST_ID'
      CacheClusterEnabled: true
      CacheClusterSize: '0.5'
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: /mypath
          HttpMethod: POST
          CachingEnabled: true
          CacheTtlInSeconds: 300
```